# Convert Hour column to datetime failes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, between

I have the following table in pandas:

```
>>>TIMESTAMP                date         Hour         patient1     patient2    patient3   patient4 ....
0  2019-06-13 12:00:00     2019-06-13   12:00:00      -0.456       -0.124      -0.451     -2.257
1  2019-06-13 12:03:00     2019-06-13   12:03:00      -0.456       -0.134      -0.781     -2.357
2  2019-06-13 12:06:00     2019-06-13   12:06:00      -0.876       -0.238      -0.983     -1.824
...
   2019-07-04 22:03:00     2019-07-04   12:03:00      -0.568       -0.532      -0.451      0.789
n  2019-07-04 22:06:00     2019-07-04   12:06:00      -0.021       -0.981      -0.293      1.824
```

I have timestamp column which is datetime and I have the column date and hour which I split from the TIMESTAMP column as following:

```
# #two cOlumns for hour and for date
df['Date'] = [d.date() for d in df['Timestamp']]
df['Hour'] = [d.time() for d in df['Timestamp']]
```

**The problem is that I want to select from my database only rows that are between 2019-06-20 to 2019-07-02  and that the hour will be between 07:00 to 17:00.That doesn't work due to problems with the datetime format.**

I was trying to do it using between:

```
df=df[(df['date'].between('2019-06-20','2019-07-02'))&(df['Hour'].between('07:00','17:00'))]
```

but then I have gotten this error:

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and
> 'str'

so I checked the dtypes and found that date and hour are object type, so I tried to  change their type like this:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour']).dt.time
```

but got error:

> TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

**My end goal is to be able to select only rows that are inside the date and hour ranges that I want (between 2019-06-20 to 2019-07-02  and that the hour will be between 07:00 to 17:00).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for remove times instead `date` and for comapre times use `time` constructor:

```
print (df)
                           date      Hour  patient1  patient2  patient3
TIMESTAMP                                                              
2019-06-13 12:00:00  2019-06-25  12:00:00    -0.456    -0.124    -0.451 <-date for match
2019-06-13 12:03:00  2019-06-13  12:03:00    -0.456    -0.134    -0.781
2019-06-13 12:06:00  2019-06-13  12:06:00    -0.876    -0.238    -0.983
2019-07-04 22:03:00  2019-07-04  12:03:00    -0.568    -0.532    -0.451
2019-07-04 22:06:00  2019-07-04  12:06:00    -0.021    -0.981    -0.293

from datetime import time

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.floor('d')
#it looks already time column, so should be removed
#df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour'].astype(str)).dt.time

df=df[(df['date'].between('2019-06-20','2019-07-02')&
       df['Hour'].between(time(7,0,0),time(17,0,0)))]

print (df)
                          date      Hour  patient1  patient2  patient3
TIMESTAMP                                                             
2019-06-13 12:00:00 2019-06-25  12:00:00    -0.456    -0.124    -0.451
```

Comment: I still get this error  message for the hour column : TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

Comment: @Reut - Tested on last pandas version `1.1.3`, maybe this is reason.

Comment: I have update my pandas and still get the same mistake.  When i'm running this and then check the dtypes it shows that only date was changed to datetime while hour hasn't

Comment: @Reut - Yes, because time column is necessary compare by `time(7,0,0),time(17,0,0))`, not be `'07:00','17:00'`

Comment: is hapenning before the between, I run only the part of the 'date' and the 'hour' to be datetime and then checking the dtypes and it doesn't change Hour to datetime

Comment: @Reut - so `df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour']).dt.time` failed? there are not object dtype, because python times?

Comment: @Reut - there cannot be datetimes, because convert datetimes to times by `dt.time`.

Comment: df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour']).dt.time  -> this failes and because of that between doesn't work

Comment: @Reut - If omit `df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour']).dt.time` it working?

Comment: doesn't work and raise the error TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

Comment: @Reut - So need `df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour'].astype(str)).dt.time` ?

Comment: that runs but still creates object type and for that the between cannot work (TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'str')

Comment: @Reut - Not understand, because `hour` is filled by `times`, compare by times `time(7,0,0),time(17,0,0)` - so where is strings? why error `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'str'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You better change the time and date to numbers (int) in the following format:
date to -> YYYYMMDD
time to -> HHMM

By the following code:

```
df['time'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%H%M').astype(int)
df['date'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)
```

Then you can easily compare with integers:

```
df=df[(df['date'].between(20190620,20190702))&(df['Hour'].between(700,1700))]
```

Comment: here the conversion work but then between doesn't work "TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=int32 and str

Comment: i'm not sure using  integers instead of  dates is correct

Comment: It is a way around to get what you are after. After this manipulation, you can drop these columns